# systemd service on startup and on shutdown requiring network access Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint, shutdown, systemd

I'm trying to setup a systemd service which executes a script after the system is fully booted (internet access is required) and also executes a different script right before the system shuts down or reboots (internet access is required).

I spend all day yesterday reading dozens of forum posts and guides but can't wrap my head around the logic.
Up until now I got:

```
[Unit]
Description=Execute custom script on shutdown
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/hostup
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/hostdown

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

My thoughts are:
The unit waits on startup for the network.target since it's required to perform the task `After=network.target`.

On service startup it executes the first script `ExecStart=/etc/init.d/hostup`.

And finally on shutdown or reboot the second script is executed `ExecStop=/etc/init.d/hostdown`

Is this even close or do I need to have two seperate services each handling one script?

Also where is the appropriate place to put these scripts. `/etc/init.d/` was just an idea.

Any input is appreciated

**EDIT:**

I invested some more time in it and I now have to separate services:

For startup:

```
Description=Custom Command on startup
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/hostup

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

and for shutdown:

```
[Unit]
Description=Execute custom script on shutdown
Before=shutdown.target network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/hostdown
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

My current problem is defining the runlevels.

when I run `sudo systemctl enable hostup.service` following error pops up:

```
Synchronizing state of hostup.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable hostup
update-rc.d: error: hostup Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

Any help on how to define the runlevels correctly would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Multi-posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504115/ .

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works for me.

Service running on shutdown:

```
[Unit]
Description=Execute custom script on shutdown
Before=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/hostdown.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target poweroff.target
```

Service running on startup:

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom Command on startup
After=network-online.target
After=network.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hostup.sh
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The latter may not be the smartest or prettiest solution and **I still don't quite understand why it won't work without this line** `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30`

Just thought I'd document my solution for the future.

**Comments and suggestions are very much welcome!**